# Display all nested groups members of a specific group using LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am looking for an LDAP query that would return all groups that are members of a certain LDAP/AD group, including all children.

Imagine this tree: A, A.1, A.2, A.1.1

I want to query A and get: 3 results: A.1, A.2, A.1.1

From my initial research it seems that is related to  LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28VS.85%29.aspx but I wasn't able to figure out the proper syntax for performing the query.

Note: this is a Microsoft Active Directory so the solution doesn't have to be generic.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure from your explanation what you are trying to accomplish, but One of [these should work](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches):

Resolves all members (including nested) security groups (requires at least Windows 2003 SP2)#

```
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

Or to retrieve only users:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

-jim